# Merging pandas dataframes with same columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge two data frames, one containing details of the win odds for a horse race and one with the place odds. They share some of the same column names. I am currently getting duplicates on the horse's names, with odds that I don't recognize. I think the problem is occurring because some races don't have a place market, only a win market so it's confusing things. Below is an example of the winning table on the left, place on the right.

```
Time   Horse      Odds   Result     Time   Horse      Odds_P Result_P     
13:55  Go faster  5.0    1          13:55  Go faster  5.0    1
14:10  Slow down  4.0    0
```

I want to just be able to add the Odds_P and Result_P for going faster on to the end of the win data frame and drop the entry that has no corresponding Place market.

I've tried concat, join and merge, all of which present me with me some duplicates of horse names, with odds that I don't recognize.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I am still not able to comprehend what you are saying. Could you please add your expected output? And also, the code you have tried perhaps?

Comment: Hi mate, sure thing. So my expected output is:

Time   Horse      Odds   Result  Odds_P Result_P
13:55  Go faster 5.0      1           5.0        1

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to put it in a nice format for you, but I basically want odds_p and result_p to join the end of the win data frame(the one on the left) and to drop the 14:10 race from the win data frame because it has no corresponding place market

Comment: i have tried : total_data = df_win.merge(df_place, on='SELECTION_NAME', how='outer') and many many other variations but I'm getting some strange results. This gets me closest to what I want, but I still get horses showing up from different races, that shouldn't be there, it's like it has a mini break down half way thru joining the data together. I know the data frames are both sound because I've gone thru and joined them both in excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your odds_p dataframe looks like:

```
    Time      Horse  Odds  Result
0  13.55  Go faster   5.0       1
1  14:10  Slow down   4.0       0
```

And result_p looks like:

```
    Time      Horse  Odds_P  Result_P
0  13.55  Go faster     5.0         1
```

I will rename the last two columns from odds_p dataframe to Odds_P and Result_P:

```
odds_p.rename(columns = {'Odds':'Odds_P', 'Result':'Result_P'}, inplace = True)
```

And now merge both using a RIGHT join:

```
final_p = pd.merge(odds_p, result_p, on = ['Time', 'Horse', 'Odds_P', 'Result_P'], how = 'right')
```

Your final output will look like:

```
    Time      Horse  Odds_P  Result_P
0  13.55  Go faster     5.0         1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help matey